# Non differentiable, continuous functions in metric spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, metric-spaces, continuity

Take the metric space $(C([0,1]),d)$ with $C([0,1])$ the set that contains all continuous functions $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R} $ and the metric $d(f,g) = \sup \{|f(x)-g(x)| : x \in [0,1]\}$.

Now, I was wondering that if we take a non differentiable, continuous function $f$ in this metric space, are there any differentiable functions in the set $B(f,\varepsilon) = \{ g \in C([0,1]) : d(f,g) < \varepsilon \}$?

I do think that this is true but that is just my intuition, can someone help me find a solution?

Comment: There are even polynomial functions...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your question is equivalent to asking

- Is it possible to approximate a continuous function *uniformly* with a differentiable one, or
- Is the set of differentiable function dense in $C([0,1])$.

Both is true and stays true if you replace "differentiable" by differentiable infintely often and can be seen by convolution with mollifiers.

Answer (score 12):

That is true. In fact, one may even take the function $g$ to be a polynomial. See [the Stone-Weierstrass approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).